# GOautodial 3.0, how to change MySql host address

Tags: mysql

How can I change the configured MySql host address?

I already installed my GOautodial on my server.

Now I want my GOautodial to connect to my database server, which is a different server than the GOautodial server.

But that IAX server won't respond when I register to the Zoiper client. I have already edited my config files `goautodial.conf` & `astguiclient.conf`, but it does not resolve that issue.

What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to run update_server_ip from your console and make sure your record server_ip is correct with your new server ip in your asterisk table.

```
 UPDATE servers SET server_ip='YOUR_NEW_IP_GOAUTODIAL' where server_ip='YOUR_OLD_IP_GOAUTODIAL';
 UPDATE phones SET server_ip='YOUR_NEW_IP_GOAUTODIAL' where server_ip='YOUR_OLD_IP_GOAUTODIAL';
 UPDATE inbound_numbers SET server_ip='YOUR_NEW_IP_GOAUTODIAL' where server_ip='YOUR_OLD_IP_GOAUTODIAL';
 UPDATE server_updater SET server_ip='YOUR_NEW_IP_GOAUTODIAL' where server_ip='YOUR_OLD_IP_GOAUTODIAL';
 UPDATE conferences SET server_ip='YOUR_NEW_IP_GOAUTODIAL' where server_ip='YOUR_OLD_IP_GOAUTODIAL';
 UPDATE vicidial_conferences SET server_ip='YOUR_NEW_IP_GOAUTODIAL' where server_ip='YOUR_OLD_IP_GOAUTODIAL';
 UPDATE vicidial_stations SET server_ip='YOUR_NEW_IP_GOAUTODIAL' where server_ip='YOUR_OLD_IP_GOAUTODIAL';
 UPDATE vicidial_remote_agents SET server_ip='YOUR_NEW_IP_GOAUTODIAL' where server_ip='YOUR_OLD_IP_GOAUTODIAL';
 UPDATE phone_favorites SET server_ip='YOUR_NEW_IP_GOAUTODIAL' where server_ip='YOUR_OLD_IP_GOAUTODIAL';
 UPDATE vicidial_server_trunks SET server_ip='YOUR_NEW_IP_GOAUTODIAL' where server_ip='YOUR_OLD_IP_GOAUTODIAL';
 UPDATE vicidial_server_carriers SET server_ip='YOUR_NEW_IP_GOAUTODIAL' where server_ip='YOUR_OLD_IP_GOAUTODIAL';
 UPDATE vicidial_inbound_dids SET server_ip='YOUR_NEW_IP_GOAUTODIAL' where server_ip='YOUR_OLD_IP_GOAUTODIAL';
 UPDATE vicidial_process_triggers SET server_ip='YOUR_NEW_IP_GOAUTODIAL' where server_ip='YOUR_OLD_IP_GOAUTODIAL';
 UPDATE servers SET rebuild_conf_files='Y' where generate_vicidial_conf='Y' and active_asterisk_server='Y';
```